# How to texture a 3d tree in opengl

Tags: opengl

I've tried to texture a tree with a *.bmp image and something I do wrong...Please help me...I have an error : undeclared identifier GL_TEXTURE_3D

```
void myinit(void);
void CALLBACK display(void);
void CALLBACK myReshape(GLsizei w, GLsizei h);
void load_texture(const char* s);
float baseRadius = 0.10;
float topRadius = 0.10;
float height = 1.0;
int slices=50, stacks=50;
float pi = 3.14159265358979323846;

GLuint IDtextura;

void load_texture(const char* s)
{   
    AUX_RGBImageRec *pImagineTextura = auxDIBImageLoad(s);

    if(pImagineTextura != NULL )
    {
        glGenTextures( 1, &IDtextura );

        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_3D, IDtextura);

        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_3D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_3D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_3D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_R, GL_REPEAT);


        glTexImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_3D, 0, 3, pImagineTextura->sizeX, pImagineTextura->sizeY,pImagineTextura->sizeZ,
            0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pImagineTextura->data);
    }

    if(pImagineTextura)
    {
        if(pImagineTextura->data )
            free(pImagineTextura->data );

        free(pImagineTextura);
    }

}
void myinit (void)
{    
    glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
     glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_3D);
    glShadeModel(GL_FLAT);
}

void CALLBACK display(void)
{
    GLUquadricObj* cilindru;
    cilindru = gluNewQuadric();

    glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glTranslatef (0.0, 0.0, -5.0);
    const char* sir;
    GLuint ID1;
        glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    sir=".\\mm.bmp";
    load_texture(sir);
    ID1=IDtextura;


    glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_3D, ID1);
    //glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        //????
    glEnd();

    glPushMatrix ();
    glRotated (0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glTranslated (0.0, 0.0, 1.5);
    glDisable (GL_LIGHTING);
    glEnable (GL_LIGHTING);
    glPopMatrix ();

    //tree
    glPushMatrix();
        glRotatef(90, 1, 0, 0);
        gluQuadricDrawStyle(cilindru, GLU_FILL);
        gluCylinder(cilindru, baseRadius, topRadius, height, slices,stacks);
    glPopMatrix();

    ..........
```

Answer (score 2):

A .bmp file is a 2D image... So you don't even have to *use* GL_TEXTURE_3D.

What you want to do is UV mapping. Texturing a 3D object doesn't require a 3D texture.

Remove glTexImage3D, use glTexImage2D instead. Same thing for glTexCoord3f.

What's more, giving 300 lines of unformatted code without real question (what you want, what you tried, etc) isn't likely to give you an answer ( But it's ok, it's your first time here )

Comment: Ok.Thank you for your answer.But I still have a problem.I don't have any error but it doesn't appear the texture,only the main color of the texture...I don't know if you understand me:)...That's why I gave the hole code...I don't know what is missing...

Comment: You have to specify texture coordinates ("UVs") for each of your triangle. Since you use GLU quadrics, you only have little control over this. For instance, see http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/documentation/manual/gluCylinder.3G.html for each quadric's UV generation : you have to call gluQuadricTexture. And again, remove all references to 3D textures.

Answer (score 1):

3D textures are part of OpenGL 1.2. On windows, in order to use OpenGL versions higher than 1.1 you need external library such as [GLEW](http://glew.sourceforge.net/) or [GLee](http://elf-stone.com/glee.php).

Comment: But I could use 2D texture for my tree?I've tried with 2d and I have an error:Unknown DIB file format...

Comment: @eueu: You are probably trying to load image format not supported by `auxDIBImageLoad`. Try different image or use different function.

Comment: @eueu : In which software do you create your .bmp ? With which options ?

Comment: I changed the picture and I don't have any error but it doesn't appear the texture,only the main color of the texture...I don't know if you understand me:)...I don't know what is missing

Comment: @eueu: I'm guessing you are not providing texture coordinates while drawing. If you are drawing with `glVertex` you can do it with [glTexCoord2f](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glTexCoord.xml). If you are drawing with `gluCylinder` use [gluQuadricTexture](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/documentation/manual/gluQuadricTexture.3G.xml).

Comment: Yes...You are right :)...Now I realised that I forgot to give the coordinates...The real problem is that I don't know to give them...What I should write in here:                glBegin(GL_QUADS);
 ?????
glEnd();

Comment: @eueu: It depends on what are you actually trying to draw. Here's a [decent example with explanation](http://nehe.gamedev.net/data/lessons/lesson.asp?lesson=06).

Comment: I saw this example but I draw a  3D tree using  GLUquadricObj* cilindru; cilindru = gluNewQuadric(); and I don't know which coordinates I should give...I don't have vertexes.

Comment: If you are drawing with gluCylinder use gluQuadricTexture.

Comment: I've used gluQuadricTexture instead of glBegin(GL_QUADS)...glEnd() and it works...I didn't gave any coordinate any more...Do you think it's correct?And I have another problem...I have 2 images .bmp which works but I if I take any other image .bmp from the internet with texture I have an error:Unknown DIB file format...I need a software or something to create a .bmp image?